# how to plot a pie of color list

Tags: python, colors, matplotlib, pie-chart

hi i have a dict with 3-int-tuple representing color (as key) and an int representing the numbers of occurences of that color in an image (as value)

for exemple, this is a 4x4 pixels image with 3 colors:
{(87, 82, 44): 1, (255, 245, 241): 11, (24, 13, 9): 4}

i want to plot a pie chart of list [1,11,4] in which each slice of the piechart is colored with the right color.. how can i do?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Update: the [other answer from Paul](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5133871/python-matplotlib-how-to-plot-a-pie-of-color-list/5134050#5134050) is much better but there's not really any point in me just editing my original answer until it's essentially the same :)  (I can't delete this answer because it's accepted.)*

Does this do what you want?  I just took [an example from the matplotlib documentation](http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/examples/pylab_examples/pie_demo.html) and turned your data into parameters that `pie()` expects:

```
# This is a trivial modification of the example here:
# http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/examples/pylab_examples/pie_demo.html

from pylab import *

data = {(87, 82, 44): 1, (255, 245, 241): 11, (24, 13, 9): 4}

colors = []
counts = []

for color, count in data.items():
    colors.append([float(x)/255 for x in color])
    counts.append(count)

figure(1, figsize=(6,6))

pie(counts, colors=colors, autopct='%1.1f%%', shadow=True)
title('Example Pie Chart', bbox={'facecolor':'0.8', 'pad':5})

show()
```

The result looks like this:

[image: The resulting pie chart]

Answer (score 3):

Mark beat me by 5 minutes, so points should go to him, but here's my (nearly identical, but more terse) answer anyway:

```
from matplotlib import pyplot

data = {(87, 82, 44): 1, (255, 245, 241): 11, (24, 13, 9): 4}
colors, values = data.keys(), data.values()
# matplotlib wants colors as 0.0-1.0 floats, not 0-255 ints
colors = [tuple(i/255. for i in c) for c in colors]
pyplot.pie(values, colors=colors)
pyplot.show()
```

Comment: +1: Not importing * is clearly more sensible :) I'd resisted using zip(*...) for splitting the items on the basis that it's bad if the list is large, but it's hardly relevant in this example...

Comment: :) Ah, I'd never noticed this useful bit in the documentation before: "If items(), keys(), values(), iteritems(), iterkeys(), and itervalues() are called with no intervening modifications to the dictionary, the lists will directly correspond."  Do you mind if I incorporate that change into my answer, with a reference to your answer?

Comment: (Apparently I can't just delete my answer now that it's been accepted, which would be my preference...)

Comment: @Mark:  Yeah, I had to look up the dict order thing too.  Your solution met all the OP's requirements with absolutely negligible performance issues for the stated use-case.  On top of that, it is much more clear and understandable, i.e. doesn't require any knowledge of list comprehensions or dictionary ordering rules.  "Better" is just a matter of opinion at this point.